# comparing rows of matrix and constructing 1D array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have [sentences*words] matrix in which rows are labeled as sentences and columns with words the code i used for that is:

```
Out = NaN(numel(sentences), numel(out_words));
for i = 1:numel(out_words)
Out(:,i) = cellfun(@(x) numel(strfind(x, out_words{i})), sentences);
end
display(Out)
```

above code returna a logical matrix a sample example below illustrates the idea:

```
  1    0   1  
  1    1   0    
  0    1   1
  1    0   1
```

in above rows are sentences and columns are words, if a word is present in a sentence 1 is written else 0 is written.
Now what i want to do is to compare the rows and save all the locations that have 1 in commmon for example in above row 1 should me compared with all the other remaining rows and row2 with all the remaining till the nth row this operation should be carried out which should save the result in 1D array as follows:

```
for example:
output=
sentence {1,2} contain red
sentence {1,4} contain red,say
sentence {2,3} contain but
sentence {1,3} contain say
and so on up till n elements
```

sentence{1,2} 1 is refered to sentence1 and 2 is sentence2 and so on till nth sentence i want to compare the rows and pick the locations on which two words have 1(true) value.

if some one can give a better idea of implementing equality relation for matrices please suggest me, thank you

Comment: Could you explain how `sentence` is filled?

Comment: actually i extracted sentences from a text file and split it after every full stop, sentences stores all the sentences in a text file code is as follows           `sentences = regexp(F,'\S.*?[\.\!\?]','match')`                                                             
`char(sentences)`

Comment: So what makes subreferencing unfeasible here? `text = {'hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'sentence'}; extracted = text([1,2,6])`. Note that this have nothing to do with equality relation, but since I only see assingment in the example I guess that assignment is where you aim.

Comment: @patrik we have full sentences here proper text not single characters for example suppose a sentence: "i like red color" here red is extracted on the basis of its frequency in the text by analyzing the text document..

Comment: and secondly this is not assignment this is the out put i want

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad and with [output](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/output) what do mean? Do you want the program to return the variable `output` (which in matlab is handled as 1) assign a value to `output` 2) return `output`) or do you want to do a printout to file or command window? It seems the meaning of "output" need to be further elaborated since the text and comments so far seems to contradict each other. Further an answer has already been submitted, but it seems OP have misinterpreted the question by looking at your comment.

Comment: @patrik i've tried to explain more in my question please read the updated question i hope u understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) to compare the sentences. Let `M` be the logical matrix of size `#sentences`-by-`#words`, then

```
cmp = bsxfun( @eq, permute(M,[1 3 2]), permute(M,[3 1 2]) )
```

Now you have a logical array `cmp` of size `#sentences`-by-`#sentences`-by-`#words` where the vector `v_ij = cmp( ii, jj, : )` has `v_ij(k) = true` iff sentence `ii` and sentence `jj` has the word `k` in them.

Comment: can u plese tell me why u have written [1 3 2] and [3 1 2] as i have a words variable that has frequent words and sentences variable that stores all the sentences in my case i have 6 words and 23 sentences.